# IBM Mobile First Direct Update from local machine

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on a project in IBM MobileFirst. My question is regarding Direct Update.

Is it possible to receive direct update if I build/deploy my application from one machine to Mobile and point the server that is in another machine (Production machine)?

If not what should I do to receive Direct Update from Production machine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your application can point to any MobileFirst Server you want, as long as that server has the application's .wlapp file deployed on it in order to register the application there (assuming also the server is properly configured to serve that application (adapters, authenticationConfig.xml, etc).

You can then deployed updated .wlapp files to that server, and it'll serve Direct Updates to registered applications.

Comment: Thanks @Idan for the quick response. Can you please tell me if my below process is the right way to deploy .wlapp files. Build application in my local machine, set up same project in IBM MF studio in production server, copy the local .wlapp file to production server. Is this how I have to do to deploy .wlapp file?